# Site not updating at all

Tags: bug, status-completed

Since the site went into read only mode then came back, it has not updated at all. According to the question list, the last newest question was five hours ago. It is the same with some of the other stack exchange sites, except for stackoverflow which hasn't undergone the server change yet.

Is this a dns propagation issue if the servers have been changed?
I include a screen shot of my front page. [image]

I probably will not be able to see my question when it appears, but I just thought I'd see if anyone else was having issues. I can only see one or two recent questions if I go to stackexchange's realtime questions list.

(I have tried it in Firefox and Chrome, rebooted Xubuntu, rebooted router, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue affected Stack Exchange as a whole.  **It has been fixed** for several minutes now.

More information is available in these Meta questions:

- [I can post questions, but they don't show up on the front page or anywhere else](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5576/83694)
- [Is my question (incorrectly) banned due to fighting with spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147246/188803)